# MySQL: Large table, slow queries, and indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a MySQL table with nearly 40 million records.  The schema looks like this:

```
id (Key field, unique)
data_type (Key field, enumeration of TXT, BIN, HEX)
line_number (Key field)
record_label (low cardinality)
record_value (high cardinality)
```

The first three fields are part of the primary key which is unique.  Queries on this table take an extremely long time even if I use one of the key fields in the query.  Research on here suggested that I needed additional indexes but I'm not sure exactly what to index.  For instance, a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE data_type = 'TXT' and id < 40000
```

which should return no more than 4,000 records runs for several minutes without returning a result.  Should I be creating an index for each field that might be used by itself as well as every possible combination of fields which might occur in a query?  What else can I do to improve performance?

Thanks.
-pv-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best index for this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE data_type = 'TXT' and id < 40000
```

is the composite index `my_table(data_type, id)`.  You can add additional columns *after* these first two.  But for this query, the first two columns need to be `data_type` and then `id`.

MySQL has pretty clear [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on the use of multi-column indexes, which might help you figure out the indexes that you really need.

Comment: Thanks.  I had looked at some index info in the MySQL docs but didn't catch this.  Led to the EXPLAIN explanation as well, so thanks.